# Geometry Nodes - Transforming simple geometry causes material (Image) to flip back and forth

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes, transforms

I have created a simple cube primitive in Blender 3.4.1 using Geometry Nodes (10m, 2m, .1m and subdivided 50 on X only).  I have also created a spiral and got the cube to conform the the spiral, basically a carpet rolling up.  All works great, the carpet rolls up and then flattens out.  I have also set up the UV and material (image) and it looks great when the carpet is flat.  The problem is when I use my slider to start to roll up the carpet the material flips from the top to the bottom of the carpet.  As I continue to roll up the carpet the image keeps flipping back/forth from top to bottom.  I created the UV with the face domain by index and after passing through the 'UV-Unwrap' node and into the 'Store Name Attribute' node that UV data is in the face corner domain. I have watched countless videos and read many articles but can't figure out any solution.  I can only assume since I'm doing this with GN there are some limitations but would really like a workaround if possible.  I basically just want to nail the image to the top side of the carpet roll regardless if the carpet is flat or if it is being rolled.  That is certainly how I thought it would have worked out of the gate.

Any guidance would be appreciated...

Comment: Images often spare a lot of text (we are essentially in a visual domain)... could you share some pictures and eventually upload a blend file preferably using https://blend-exchange.com/)

Comment: Hey Lemon, thanks for the reply...  I realize that an image is worth a 1000 words and that there could be many causes of my issue and thus your request for me to provide more information.  I will work on uploading some more info when I get time.  Was hoping that this was something that was known and could be easily answered.  I guess what I'm describing is not normal behavior?

Comment: @Ray2023 .. could be quite a few things.. I think your best bet would be to share a minimal representative file on https://blend-exchange.com/ . If the itexture-mage is huge, perhaps pack a smaller test image which behaves the same way into your .blend file.